# Unlimited images, responsiveness, fluid square/grid gallery, with a min and max size of images, but always less than 10px container margin

Tags: html, css, flexbox, image-gallery

Here is my goal:
- full width of container no matter the screen size (meaning, the image size is dynamic where image size always fits a full row of images)
- the images will ALWAYS be squares, but no smaller than 150px and no larger than 200px
- a 10px margin between images and rows

So basically, how to change or add to this codepen, where there isn't the big right/left margin depending your screen size?
https://codepen.io/trynn/pen/WNbjOJq

You need to calculate the screen to image size, right?
thanks

This css doesn't adjust the size of the images, but it needs too? Then by doing so, it would/could adjust the image size and make sure only a 10px margin is left, no matter the screen size? Isn't that correct?

```
     .container{
              display: flex;
              flex-wrap: wrap;
              justify-content: center;
     }
     img{
              margin: 5px;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Images can scale with one side set to `auto` but the other side needs to be set to an exact size. Strangely enough, when I worked with this, the images were able to be fluid despite being set to an exact size.

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: wow! that is very interesting.  If using max-width, that solves the problem for the last row if not full... prevents from having images width being stretched. But then the margins looks to be split the width?  Both sides 100px (ish).

But very cool that such an easy way to use CSS almost works perfectly.